# Creating multi dimensional array with map method: javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, undefined

Here is how I tried creating a 2D array:

`var data = new Array(10);` // an array of length 10 all elements undefined

```
var twoDArray = data.map(function (d){
    return new Array(20);    // expected to be 2d array, but 10 elements all undefined
});
```

**But** now if I do the following I get results as expected:

```
var data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var twoDArray = data.map(function (d){
    return new Array(20);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `.map` won't iterate over the values because they are all `undefined`.

You could use:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(function() {
   return new Array(20);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; **it is not invoked for indexes that are undefined**, those which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

Thus you can't use `map` with an array full of `undefined`.